# C++ operator lookup rules / Koenig lookup

Tags: c++, argument-dependent-lookup

While writing a test suite, I needed to provide an implementation of `operator<<(std::ostream&...` for Boost unit test to use.

This worked:

```
namespace theseus { namespace core {
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& ss, const PixelRGB& p) {
        return (ss << "PixelRGB(" << (int)p.r << "," << (int)p.g << "," << (int)p.b << ")");
    }
}}
```

This didn't:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& ss, const theseus::core::PixelRGB& p) {
    return (ss << "PixelRGB(" << (int)p.r << "," << (int)p.g << "," << (int)p.b << ")");
}
```

Apparently, the second wasn't included in the candidate matches when g++ tried to resolve the use of the operator. Why (what rule causes this)?

The code calling `operator<<` is deep within the Boost unit test framework, but here's the test code:

```
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE(core_image)

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(test_output) {
    using namespace theseus::core;
    BOOST_TEST_MESSAGE(PixelRGB(5,5,5)); // only compiles with operator<< definition inside theseus::core
    std::cout << PixelRGB(5,5,5) << "\n"; // works with either definition
    BOOST_CHECK(true); // prevent no-assertion error
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE_END()
```

For reference, I'm using g++ 4.4 (though for the moment I'm assuming this behaviour is standards-conformant).

Comment: From what scope were you trying to use your `operator<<` ?

Comment: @Charles: I've edited to add the test code.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In argument dependent lookup (the correct name for koenig lookup) the compiler adds to the overloaded function set the functions which are declared in the namespaces of each parameter.

In your case, the first `operator<<` is declared in the namespace `thesus::core,` which is the type of the argument you call the operator with.  Therefore this `operator<<` is considered for ADL because it's declared in an associated namespace

In the second case, the `operator<<` seems to be declared in the global namespace which is not an associated namespace as parameter one is of type from namespace `std` and param 2 is of type from namespace `theseus::core`.

Actually, probably your 2nd `operator<<` isn't declared in global namespace as that would be found through looking in parent scopes..  maybe you've got something more like this? If you can post more code we can give a better answer.

---

Ok  I remembered, ADL doesn't lookup in parent scopes when it finds a name in the current scope.  So the boost macro `BOOST_TEST_MESSAGE` expands to include an `operator<<` and there is some in the scope tree a non-viable `operator<<` between the expression and global scope. I updated code to illustrate this (hopefully).

```
#include <iostream>

namespace NS1
{
  class A
  {};

  // this is found by expr in NS2 because of ADL
  std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream &, NS1::A &);
}


// this is not seen because lookup for the expression in NS2::foo stops when it finds the operator<< in NS2
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream &, NS1::A &);

namespace NS2
{
    class B
    {};

    // if you comment this out lookup will look in the parent scope
    std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream &, B &);

    void foo(NS1::A &a)
    {
        std::cout << a;
    }  
}
```

Comment: Exactly, and the global namespace is not associated because the boost unit-test stuff is not global. This is a feature to prevent non-intended injection of functions into template-code.

Comment: hmm..   ok global not associated, but a viable operator<< in global scope should be found by lookup through parent scopes no ?

Comment: The second operator<< is declared in global namespace (it appears before any boost unit test macros that might affect scope). So why wouldn't parent scope lookup find it?

Comment: (unaccepted -- I'll re-accept when the parent/global scope thing has been cleared up)

Comment: @dancl: Code formatting on SO works by indenting the code by four spaces, not by using `<code>`-tags.

Comment: re why global scope not found, i remembered the reason; lookup stops looking in parent scopes when it finds a name in the current scope.  ADL will always happen once this lookup has finished.

Comment: @danci: That explains it then. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Operator overloading is like a function but differs, and one of the differences is namespace lookup.

Like functions, operator overloads belong in a namespace, but scoping the way you scope a function would be impractical. Imagine if your code had to call

```
std::cout thesus::core::<< p; // ouch and obviously incorrect syntax
```

Therefore the `<<` operator must be in the namespace of one of the parameters, either `std` (for the `cout`) or the namespace of the `p`, in this case `thesus::core`.

This is the Koenig Lookup principle. You must define the operator overload in the correct namespace.

Comment: The lookup rules for resolving overloaded operators are exactly the same as for overloaded functions.

Comment: @Charles: Yes, though name hiding behaviour differs subtly. Well not so subtly, really... http://stackoverflow.com/q/24168137/560648