# Are there different rules regarding ADL or naming clashes with regard to overloaded operators?

Tags: c++, argument-dependent-lookup, token-name-resolution

I think this example best illustrates my question:

```
namespace N {

    class C {
    public:
        friend bool operator==(const C& c, const C& x) {
            return true;
        }
        friend bool f(const C& c, const C& x) {
            return true;
        }
    };

    class D {
    public:
        bool operator==(const D& x) {
            bool a = C{} == C{};      // this works
            return true;
        }
        bool f(const D& x) {
            bool a = f(C{}, C{});     // this does not work
            return true;
        }
    };
}
```

I have always viewed overloaded operators as being just like function except for the 'calling syntax' if you will. I just noticed the above difference however in ADL or name lookup rules (I don't know which one).

Can someone explain why the `bool operator==(const C& c, const C& x)` is found but the `bool f(const C& c, const C& x)` is not?

Comment: Note that this is hiding, not ADL, since everything is in the same namespace. ADL is about looking up the function in additional *namespaces* (in particular, the namespaces in which the parameters' types are defined).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `D::f` is *hiding* `C::f`; if you rename the latter to `C::g` and adjust the call then it works fine (showing that the function can be *found* and *accessed* just fine).

Your code isn't actually directly calling the operator functions, but this is done for you by the language. Consequently you're not using the *name* of the operator function, so no name hiding applies.

If you write `operator==(C{}, C{})` (instead of `C{} == C{}`), then you'll see the same behaviour as `f(C{}, C{})` ([demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4658c249feb00f3b)).

So, when you say "I have always viewed overloaded operators as being just like function except for the 'calling syntax' if you will", you've already hit the nail on the head.

---

Here's some standardese for you:

> `[C++11: 13.5/4]:` Operator functions are usually not called directly; instead they are invoked to evaluate the operators they implement (13.5.1 – 13.5.7). They can be explicitly called, however, using the *operator-function-id* as the name of the function in the function call syntax (5.2.2). *[ Example:*
>
> ```
> complex z = a.operator+(b); // complex z = a+b;
> void* p = operator new(sizeof(int)*n);
> ```
>
> *—end example ]*
>
> `[C++11: 3.3.7/4]:` *[..]* 4) A name declared within a member function hides a declaration of the same name whose scope extends to or past the end of the member function’s class. *[..]*
>
> `[C++11: 3/4]:` A name is a use of an *identifier* (2.11), *operator-function-id* (13.5), *literal-operator-id* (13.5.8), *conversion-function-id* (12.3.2), or *template-id* (14.2) that denotes an entity or *label* (6.6.4, 6.1).

(The [qualified] *operator-function-id* here is `::N::C::operator==`.)